# Joining a Docker swarm

Tags: docker

I have 2 VMs.

On the first I run:

```
docker swarm join-token manager
```

On the second I run the result from this command.

i.e.

```
docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-0wyjx6pp0go18oz9c62cda7d3v5fvrwwb444o33x56kxhzjda8-9uxcepj9pbhggtecds324a06u 192.168.65.3:2377
```

However, this outputs:

```
Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 192.168.65.3:2377: connect: connection refused"
```

Any idea what's going wrong?

If it helps I'm spinning up these VMs using Vagrant.

Comment: connectivity issues between the two VMs? I would run a tcpdump in the swarm master to sniff incomming connection

Answer (score 5):

Just add the port to firewall on master side 
firewall-cmd --add-port=2377/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload

Then again try docker swarm join on second VM or node side

Answer (score 3):

I did `firewall-cmd --add-port=2377/tcp --permanent firewall-cmd --reload` already on master side and was still getting the same error.
I did `telnet <master ip> 2377` on worker node and then I did `reboot` on master.
Then it is working fine.

Comment: I was facing the same error ` Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 172.17.0.1:2377: connect: connection refused" `
I realized that it was because I was using two VMs and I needed to use FQDN instead of ip. After replacing the ip in the join cluster command I was able to get it working

Answer (score 3):

I was facing similar issue. and I spent couple of hours to figure out the root cause and share to those who may have similar issues.

### Environment:

- Oracle Cloud + AWS EC2 (2 +2)
- OS:  20.04.2-Ubuntu
- Docker version : 20.10.8
- 3 dynamic public IP+ 1 elastic IP

### Issues

1. create two instances on the Oracle cloud at beginning
2. A instance (manager) docker swarm init  --advertise-addr  success
3. B instance (worker) docker join as worker is worker success
4. when I try to promo B as manager, encountered error

> Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
> 5. mesh routing is not working properly.

### Investigation

1. Suspect it is related to network/firewall/Security group/security list
2. ssh to B server (worker), telnet (manager) 2377, with same error

> Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
> 3. login oracle console and add ingress rule under security list for all of relative port
> TCP port 2377 for cluster management communications

> TCP and UDP port 7946 for communication among nodes

> UDP port 4789 for overlay network traffic
> 4. try again but still not work with telnet for same error
> 5. check the OS level firewall. if has disable it.
> systemctl ufw disable
> 6. try again but still not work with same result
> 7. I suspect there have something wrong with oracle cloud, then I decide try to use AWS install the same version of OS/docker
> 8. add security group to allow all of relative ports/protocol and disable ufw
> 9. test with AWS instance C (leader/master) + D (worker). it works and also can promote D to manager. mesh routing was also work.
> 10. confirm the issue with oracle cloud
> 11. try to join the oracle instance (A) to C as worker. it works but still cannot promote as manager.
> 12. use journalctl -f  to investigate the log and confirm there have socket timeout from A/B (oracle instances) to AWS instance(C)
> 13. relook the A/B, found there have iptables block request
> 14. remove all of setup in the iptables

```html
# remove the rules
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -F
```

```
 15. remove all of setup in the iptables
```

### Root Cause

```
It caused by firewall either in cloud security/WAF/ACL level or OS firewall/rules. e.g. ufw/iptables
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. 
But can u edit ur answer to specify remove iptables of Master or Worker or both?
I remove from both. and is there any drawback or security risk to remove iptables?

Comment: iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT && iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT && iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT && iptables -F

this would be better command to run in one line

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your docker swarm manager leader is not running on port 2377. You can check it  by firing this command on your swarm manager leader vm. If it is working just fine then you will get similar output

```
[root@host1]# docker node ls
ID                            HOSTNAME                     STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS
tilzootjbg7n92n4mnof0orf0 *   host1    Ready               Active              Leader
```

Furthermore you can check the listening ports in leader swarm manager node. It should have port tcp 2377 for cluster management communications and tcp/udp port 7946 for communication among nodes opened.

```
[root@host1]# netstat -ntulp | grep dockerd
tcp6       0      0 :::2377                 :::*                    LISTEN      2286/dockerd
tcp6       0      0 :::7946                 :::*                    LISTEN      2286/dockerd
udp6       0      0 :::7946                 :::*                                2286/dockerd
```

In the second vm where you are configuring second swarm manager you will have to make sure you have connectivity to port 2377 of leader swarm manager. You can use tools like telnet, wget, nc to test the connectivity as given below

```
[root@host2]# telnet <swarm manager leader ip> 2377
Trying 192.168.44.200...
Connected to 192.168.44.200.
```

Comment: for my case,  I can confirm the port is LISTEN on port 2377. I create another instance (worker) with open firewall rule on the related port e.g. 2377 tcp.  However it shows me error "telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host"  not sure what is an issue.  PS: i am try to telnet leader node on port 22 from worker node, it works. but not work for port 2377.  OS: 20.04.2-Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

For me I was on linux and windows. My windows docker private network was the same as my local network address. So docker daemon wasn't able to find in his own network the master with the address I was giving to him.
So I did :

```
1- go to Docker Desktop app 
2- go to Settings 
3- go to Resources 
4- go to Network section and change the Docker subnet address (need to be different from your local subnet address). 
5- Then apply and restart. 
6- use the docker join on the worker again.
```

Note: All this steps are performed on the node where the error appear. Make sure that the ports 2377, 7946 and 4789 are opens on the master (you can use iptables or ufw).

Hope it works for you.